# Is there a Java API or shortcut for a state name lookup/find?

Tags: java, api, if-statement

I'm writing a program that takes in a string, a state name (for example New York), and outputs the corresponding abbreviation (e.g. NY). My program considers all 50 states, so my first thought was to use a boatload of `if/else if` statements, but now I'm thinking there's gotta be a better way...a faster way...without so much seemingly redundant code.

Snippet:

```
if (dirtyState.equalsIgnoreCase("New York")) {
        cleanState = "NY";
    } else if (dirtyState.equalsIgnoreCase("Maryland")) {
        cleanState = "MD";
    } else if (dirtyState.equalsIgnoreCase("District of Columbia")) {
        cleanState = "DC";
    } else if (dirtyState.equalsIgnoreCase("Virginia")) {
        cleanState = "VA";
    } else if (dirtyState.equalsIgnoreCase("Alabama")) {
        cleanState = "AL";
    } else if (dirtyState.equalsIgnoreCase("California")) {
        cleanState = "CA";
    } else if (dirtyState.equalsIgnoreCase("Kentuky")) {
        cleanState = "KY";
        // and on and on...
```

Is there an API that could make this process simpler? A shortcut perhaps?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) which allows you to use a custom comparator that is case insensitive. It would look like this:

```
Map<String, String> states = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
states.put("New York", "NY");
states.put("Maryland", "MD");
//etc.
```

And to retrieve an abbreviation:

```
String abbreviation = states.get("new york");
System.out.println(abbreviation); //prints NY
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to grab a [city code list](http://www.bennetyee.org/ucsd-pages/area.html) and put it in a properties file like:

```
New York=NY
Maryland=MD
District of Columbia=DC
Virginia=VA
```

Then load the content in a [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and loop on its entries (it extends [HashTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)):

```
Properties cityCodes = new Properties() 
citycodes.load(new FileInputStream(...));

for(Entry<String,String> entry : cityCodes.entrySet()){
  if(dirtyState.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey())){
    cleanState = entry.getValue();
  }
}
```

Here is a working example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  Properties cityCodes = new Properties();
  cityCodes.load(new FileInputStream("/path/to/directory/cityCodes.properties"));
  System.out.print(getCode("Maryland",cityCodes));
}

public static String getCode(String name, Properties cityCodes){
  for(Map.Entry<Object,Object> entry : cityCodes.entrySet()){
    String cityName=(String)entry.getKey();
    String cityCode=(String)entry.getValue();

    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(cityName)){
      return cityCode;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

**Output:**

```
MD
```

Comment: good idea, but how would I code that? and would I just put the list (as a csv) in the prop file?

Comment: I edited the answer to add a working example.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 7 you can use strings in a switch statement, e.g.:

```
switch (dirtyState.toLowerCase())
{ 
   case "new york": cleanState = "NY"; break;
   case "maryland": cleanState = "MD"; break;
   // so on...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an enum:

```
public enum State {
    AL("Alabama"), CA("California"), NY("New York");

    private State(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

    static String findByName(String name) {
        for ( int i = 0; i != values().length; ++i ) {
            if ( name.equalsIgnoreCase(values()[i].name))
                return values()[i].toString();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }    
}

public class StateTest {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "New York";
        System.out.println(name + ": " + State.findByName(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this way too, thanks!